# How do i add Mailgun variables into a template?

Tags: codeigniter, mailgun

I've just started using mailgun, and i've created a template on their dashboard.

In my codeigniter project i've added the following code :

```
$this->mailgun::send([
  'from' => "ZooTopia <no-reply@zoop.com>",
  'to' => "XXXXXXX@gmail.com",
  'subject' => "Welcome to BB.com",
  'text' => "We just want to say hi. Have fun at Example.com",
    'template' => "test",
    'v:name' => "Jamie"
]);
```

I want to be able to display the variable for name onto the transactional email template i've created on the mailgun site.

I tried %name% but that doesn't seem to work.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What is your template code?

try to use {{name}} instead of %name%

Mailgun is using https://handlebarsjs.com/ for templates

also try to replace

`'v:name' => "Jamie"`

to:

`'h:X-Mailgun-Variables'    => '{"name": "Jamie"}'`